# Getting My Hands on Something New

Tags: cryptography, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, data-mining, robotics

I am not sure if this question is relevant to this Stackexchange site or not, but here it goes.

I have just graduated in Computer Science and I will be on my Job from next month onwards. Till now, during college, I did most of what was in the course structure without really exploring much. I like Algorithm Designing, and tend to keep working on that for the rest of my time by solving a myriad of problems available online. **EDIT** Apart from this I have covered **Databases**, the basic stuff that is how to retrieve, manipulate data and also the Indexing [though I scarcely remember much of it], **Operating System**, read about it, the processes, and file system [ a bit weak ], **Computer Networks** etc., that is the all the basic courses that are expected of a CS graduate.

Now, I wanted to learn something new in the field of Computer Science. I want to take it up, and read about it, and maybe work on some small and simple project, so that I feel confident enough, like I fee about Data Structures [though I am still learning, but having worked with it for a decent span of time, I have started to feel confidant about Data Structures.] I am in no rush, and would like to work for an year on it, since with my job at hand, it'll be difficult to devote time, like I could while in college.

Now, if someone were to suggest some branch of Computer Science, that fits my interests and will be interesting to work with. Also, along with it, a head start on where I can begin learning about the same, maybe, books or other material.

Interests : Logical Thinking, Algorithm Designing, Software Level [I never like Microprocessors or Computer Architecture].

Also, I read about different branches of Computer Science, and Artificial Intelligence really excited me, since it sounds cool, but I am not sure if it is as exciting to work with, as it sounds.

**EDIT** It's not exactly Artificial Intelligence That I am looking for, I just want to explore a new branch of Computer Science and would love to know from the people in those fields, about what to expect and what not to. I am as ignorant of AI as any other field.

I am not which Stack Overflow tag would go the best with this question, hence I just added Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence and all others that I could think of [Limit on tags is 5]

I've spent so much time with the basic coding stuff and solving problems [ though I still have not done even 0.1% of the stuff out there], but I think I would want to take on something new and exciting to keep me occupied and hooked even more.

PS : If this portal is not suited for such questions, let me know, if I can ask it on any other StackExchange website. I'll take it down.

**EDIT**

I am 22 years of age. I got a job offer from a decent firm right after college, and had planned to go for MS, after a couple of years of job, [having made some money for the college]. But a few days back I was going through the Courses offered by the universities like Carnegie Mellon, Cornell etc. and it hit me if I really needed a Masters Degree. If I really needed the certification that I know something , rather than knowing the stuff in real. And I inferred that all I want is to know stuff, and know it deep. I am fairly diligent student, and pretty sure of my capabilities. If I set out to achieve something that excites me, I do achieve that most of the times. And even after MS, my main motive would be to get a decent paying job, but I guess, I'd want to learn even then. And in the end, maybe own something of my own. Some little 'Technical Venture' that may be as simple as it could be,yet something of my own. And Hence for that, I guess, I don't really need MS, if I can study on my own. I know it will be difficult to maintain it with my current job at hand, but my passion for learning will drive me forward. I want to pick up something afresh, that is exciting and that I can work with for a good year or so. And if I feel that I've done enough with that particular field, I'll try to pick up something new.

So kindly pour in your valuable thoughts and help motivate a rigorous learner.

Comment: Don't have a great spot to migrate this to, but you're correct in surmising that this site isn't a great fit, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: For the interest of [Artificial Intelligence](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) this is, as far as I can tell, the de facto standard as an introduction.  Usually split into two courses, and there's code for various languages like C++, Java, and Lisp.  AI is hard - there's a reason no one has 'solved' it yet - but it's very rewarding.

Comment: I've made some Edits as recommended, to reopen the put-on-hold question.

Comment: @Ross http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Or for more specific CS related questions, try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @owlstead Is there any way I can put this question on a different stackexchange site, without having to draft the entire Question again?

Comment: @Kraken Not directly but you could flag it for moderator attention, I think it would only be fit for programmers though, if that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember studying Artificial Intelligence, and I think it can be as cool as you think it will be. It's just really hard! Also, not sure what the job opportunities are like.

If it's something you'd like to play with though, I'd recommend doing a bit of reading with neural networks. I think they're a little outdated now, but I remember they showed me what sort of things can be done with AI.

I'm afraid I can't think of any resources on it at the moment, but there should be loads of introductions out there.

Comment: Don't start with neural networks. Start with a statistics class.

Comment: Yeah, there's loads of maths involved.  A scary amount.  I agree, if you're au fait with heavy-duty statistical maths (many Comp Sci courses are), then that's fine, but you need a good grounding in maths to do loads of these advanced topics.

Comment: Otherwise you're just doing something without really knowing what it is you're doing.